# I remember my father "taking" me to the zoo when I was a child

Tags: past-tense

> I remember my father **taking** me to the zoo when I was a child.

the above sentence has three clauses:

1. I remember.
2. My father taking me to the zoo.
3. I was child.

What is the tense of the second clause? and can we replace it with *used to* or *simple past*? which one of the following is close in meaning to the above sentence?

> 1. I remember my father **used to take** me to the zoo when I was a child.
> 2. I remember my father **took** me to the zoo when I was a child.

**Update:**

Why do I think there should be tense and verb in this sentence:

First,

> A clause is the basic unit of grammar. Typically a main clause is made up of a subject (s) (a noun phrase) and a **verb** phrase (v) ... [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/clauses)

So, if I'm right and the above (*my father taking me to the zoo*) is clause, so I presume that there is a verb and the verb should has a tense.

Second,

> We can form passive structures with **verbs** that are followed by an object (transitive verbs) and some clauses where the verb is followed by a preposition ... [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passive/passive)

And I can convert the above clause to *passive voice* as following. So, What do I convert? Isn't the verb? and Doesn't this verb has a tense?

> I remember **being taken** to the zoo when I was a child ...

Comment: There is no tense in *present particles* (despite the name).

Comment: Thank you, I'll update the question to describe why I think there is a tense and verb

Comment: If you're remembering, it means you're re-living the moment, so the action is in the present from that perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clare is quite right: an *-ing* form<sup>†</sup> is not marked for any tense (time reference). Only finite verbs are marked for tense, either past (*he took*) or non-past (*he takes*).

Context permits us to *attribute* a time reference to the clause which the *-ing* form heads, but that time reference is not a property of the verb. In your example, for instance, the clause headed by *taking* is understood to have a past time reference because **a)** the clause in which it is embedded is headed by a verb which entails a past reference in its complement—we don't ordinarily "remember" eventualities which are happening now or which we expect to happen in the future—and **b)** this clause is modified by a temporal locative which explicitly locates the eventuality in the past.

Neither of your active rewrites expresses quite the same thing as your original example.

- > I remember my father **used to take** me to the zoo when I was a child.

  There is no warrant in the original for the habitual *used to*: the original entails only that the event took place on at least one occasion but is silent as to whether the event took place on multiple occasions.
- > I remember my father took me to the zoo when I was a child.

  There is a very slight difference between **A)** remembering *X doing Y* and **B)** remembering *that X did Y*: in A you assert the **fact** of the event, while in B you assert your present memory of the event itself. But in most cases the difference is unimportant.

Aside from eliminating the Agent of the verb, your passive rewrite is fine; like the original it is headed by an *-ing* form which is marked for no particular tense of its own: the tense of the clause it heads is inferred from context.

---

<sup>†</sup>Traditional grammar gives this form two different names, *gerund* or *present participle*, depending on its syntactic function. *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* calls it a gerund-participle.